# How can i change TTL of DNS packet created using dns python?

Tags: python, dns, ttl, dnspython

The idea is to send DNS packet with increasing TTL so as to find out if intermediate node has sent reply or not.
So i want to send DNS packet multiple time with increasing TTL.
How to change TTL of packet while sending it.
I am using dns python to send out packet